# Like statement in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sql-like

If I enter an input into the textbox, my listview updates, but there is always no result even though my input is there.

```
Private Sub searchRecord()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM tblSupplier WHERE '" & cboSearch.Text 
                      & "' LIKE '" & txtSearch.Text & "%'")
    lvSupplier.Items.Clear()
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For ctr = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim item As New ListViewItem
            item.Text = dt.Rows(ctr)("SuppID")
            item.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(ctr)("SuppName"))
            item.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(ctr)("SuppAddress"))
            item.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(ctr)("SuppConPerson"))
            item.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(ctr)("SuppConNumber"))
            item.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(ctr)("SuppEmail"))
            lvSupplier.Items.Add(item)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt = ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM tblSupplier")

Try
    If txtSearch.Text = "" Then
        Call fillSupplier(dt, lvSupplier)
    Else
        Call searchRecord()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

Comment: Try `WHERE " & cboSearch.Text & " LIKE ` - without single quotes around cbo

Comment: if i remove single quote, incorrect syntax near keyword LIKE

Comment: Did u remove them around `cboSearch.Text` or around `txtSearch.Text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL statement should be like this...

```
"SELECT * FROM tblSupplier WHERE " & cboSearch.Text & " LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text.Replace("'","''").Trim() & "%'"
```

This way you should be able to search for any character or word wherever it's placed in the original word or phrase found in the database.

Comment: What's the value for cboSearch.Text? I've been using LIKE clause for as long as I can remember and I don't see anything wrong with it. Let's troubleshoot this bit by bit. Take note that field names should never be within single quotes. The only thing I could think of is that you used a RESERVED Name for the field name. Using RESERVED Names such as Name, Date, etc. can cause SQL to misunderstand the query statement. Instead of using RESERVED Names, use fldNAME, fldDATE and so on for field names...

Comment: If you add the quotes for cboSearch.Text, SQL will execute it with no error, the reason you're not getting any result is the fact that if you add the quotes, it means you're querying all data that are have the same characters as cboSearch.Text...LITERALLY, and it doesnt make any sense.

Comment: I just copy pasted it from my professors codes, did i miss something, or i need to import something to use those? Thanksss!

Comment: Hmmmm, I know how hard it is to start programming. I learned programming on my own with nobody to teach me. I remember reading the same basic stuff over and over again just so I could understand. I'd sleep at 3 am studying. So I think it won't do harm if I make you a project with the functionality you want just this once so you could proceed further. What's your email address?

Comment: @Ninay11, I got a Mailer-Daemon Notice...Are you sure you got me the right email address?

Comment: still dont receive anything :/ can u try sending it here sir 

---- edz0603@yahoo.com

Comment: Received the file. Ill be trying it in a minute.

Comment: the functionality is ok, i need to study this and change codes because im using SQL database XD

Comment: It doesn't matter which database you're using. Some database may have its own formatting techniques, but they're generally the same. I use mysql, access, sql server, sybase... You just have to change the connectionstring and you're good to go. I use access during the development stage, then migrate everything to a server type database when it's ready to be deployed. Keep in mind that if you want compatibility over speed, choose OLEDB Client, if you want speed over compatibility, choose SQL Client. You shouldn't see any difference in speed unless you're querying millions of data.

Comment: Replace the connectionstring to this. "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DATABASENAME;Uid=USERNAME;Pwd=PASSWORD;". No need to change the internal code. It works.